# getting error while deploying Microsoft enterprise bot template on azure

Tags: azure, deployment, botframework

I created a bot with the Microsoft Enterprise Bot Template, and now I want to deploy it to Azure. I am following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), but I am getting the following error after the following command

Command :

```
msbot clone services --name "YOUR_BOT_NAME" 
                     --luisAuthoringKey "YOUR_AUTHORING_KEY" 
                     --folder "DeploymentScripts\LOCALE_FOLDER" 
                     -- location "REGION"
```

Error:

```
Command failed: az group create -g MyBot -l "region" --subscription KEY 
ERROR: The client 'abcd' with object id '679ebaf5-4345-408c-87ef- 
9c3bd2795a94' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope 
'/subscriptions/abcd/resourcegroups/MyBot'.
```

Comment: The troubleshooting doc discusses the necessary permissions, and how to set them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#why-do-i-get-an-authorization_requestdenied-exception-when-creating-a-bot

Answer (score 3):

this means you lack permissions to perform this action, you need to grant your service principal\user permissions (contributor is the easiest way to solve this) to perform that operation. you can grant them on specific resource group or on the subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Comment: how can ensure that i have all rights becuase my IT guy says you have the rights on azure.

Comment: well, show him the error, you clearly dont have rights. the easiest way to solve this is grant contributor level permissions

Answer (score 1):

you need to have contributor access on the resource group that you are creating the bot in.

also ensure that Microsoft.BotService is a registered service on the subscription.

Comment: thats not true, you can get away with a lot less permissions